# visualize simulations/iterations as a confidence interval in box plot python?

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, data-visualization, boxplot

I have a data with values generated based simulated iterations (for eg. 100) and am trying to visualize the variation of mean/median, first and third quartile over the 100 iterations as a shaded confidence interval around in the box plot. I am having a hard time trying to find example work representation of simulations/iterations in a boxplot, and was wondering if anyone has some direction. Appreciate your suggestions. The picture below is an example of sample output I am trying to achieve.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools




def generate_dataframe():
    # Create a pandas dataframe...

    _type = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] *2500
    _shares = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(10000)]
    lst = range(1,101)    
    _iterations = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 100) for x in lst))
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
         'Type': _type,
         'shares': _shares,
         'iteration': _iterations
        })



df = generate_dataframe()
#df.boxplot(column = 'shares', by=['Type', 'iteration'])
df.boxplot(column = 'shares', by='Type')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are very close. You just need to add `plt.show()` at the end of your code to make this

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

def generate_dataframe():
    # Create a pandas dataframe...

    _type = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] *2500
    _shares = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(10000)]
    lst = range(1,101)    
    _iterations = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 100) 
for x in lst))
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
         'Type': _type,
         'shares': _shares,
         'iteration': _iterations
        })

df = generate_dataframe()
df.boxplot(column = 'shares', by='Type')
plt.show()
```

Comment: appreciate your suggestion, I am able to plot a boxplot, but the issue is representing the iterations as a confidence interval over first and quartile and median.